# How do I get the FileNode for readDictionary() (OpenCV)?

Tags: python, dictionary, file, opencv, yaml

I want to read a Dictionary out of a file (I use a yaml file, not sure if its the right choice).
So I can successfully write into the file with following code:

```
aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_100)
file_storage = cv2.FileStorage("DictionaryFile.yml", cv2.FILE_STORAGE_WRITE)
aruco_dict.writeDictionary(file_storage)
file_storage.release()
```

The Dicitonary is saved as it shows in the [opencv doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d0b/classcv_1_1aruco_1_1Dictionary.html).

Now I want to read the file and save it to a new Dictionary. But for `Dictionary.readDictionary()` I need a `FileNode` ... Where and how do I get the right filenode?

I tried following:

```
file_storage = cv2.FileStorage("DictionaryFile.yml", cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
custom_dict=cv2.aruco.Dictionary.readDictionary(file_storage.root())
file_storage.release()
```

It is probably the worst try possible. I am pretty new to OpenCV and Python. I found a few forum answers with np arrays. If that is a better way, how do I use that?

Comment: On the (official) FAQ on yaml.org, the recommended extension for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006. YML is a derivative of XML.